# Multiple Authentication Login Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to create a login function that if you visit the homepage as guest it should show all the login options as show in the @else statement then if you logged in as an admin it should only show Home in the top right corner as same with the other 3. The error shows unexpected end of file

```
   <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
        @if (Route::has('admin.login'))
            <div class="top-right links">
               @auth('admin')
                    <a href="{{ route('admin.login') }}">Home</a>

        @elseif (Route::has('cashier.login'))
                @auth('cashier')
                    <a href="{{ route('cashier.login') }}">Cashier Login</a>

         @elseif (Route::has('kitchen.login'))
                @auth('kitchen')
                    <a href="{{ route('kitchen.login') }}">Kitchen Login</a>  
        @elseif (Route::has('login'))  
                @auth
                    <a href="{{ route('cashier.login') }}">Cashier Login</a>
        @else

                    <a href="{{ route('admin.login') }}">Admin Login</a> 
                    <a href="{{ route('cashier.login') }}">Cashier Login</a>
                    <a href="{{ route('cashier.login') }}">Cashier Login</a>
                    <a href="{{ route('kitchen.login') }}">Kitchen Login</a> 

          @endauth
            </div>
        @endif
```

Comment: `The error shows unexpected end of file` could you take a peek on the generated view? its located in `/storage/view` i believe.

Comment: you should have a good patient when debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Close each `@auth` with `@endauth`

**Example**

```
@auth('admin')
    <a href="{{ route('admin.login') }}">Home</a>
@endauth
```

**NB**

I think it'd be better if you separated nav items into partials for each type of user, so each partial will have full navbar logic for a given user:

```
@auth('admin')
    @include('partials._nav-admin')
@endauth
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be tutorial of multi auth in laravel 5.4

link: https://ysk-override.com/Multi-Auth-in-Laravel-54-Login-20170203/